# Função date mostra o valor errado dos minutos no PHP

Tags: php, data

Estou com um problema com a data e a hora com PHP mesmo definindo a região usando  `date_default_timezone_set(America/Sao_Paulo)`, ele está dando de diferença quase 30 minutos:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o código para gerar esta tela:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');

setlocale(LC_ALL, 'pt_BR');
 $data = ini_get('date.timezone');    echo "Fuso Horario do servidor <b>".$data."</b>";?>
             <?php $data = date_default_timezone_get(); echo "<br>Fuso horario do sistema <b> ".$data."</b>";?>
             <?php $data      = date("e");      echo "<br>Fuso horario do sistema : <b>".$data."</b>";?>
             <? $script_tz = date_default_timezone_get();
                if (strcmp($script_tz, ini_get('date.timezone'))){
                    echo '<br>O fuso horário do sistema difere do fuso horário servidor. Porem isso não é um problema';
                } else {
                    echo '<br>Fuso horário de Sistema e fuso horário de servidor iguais !';
                }
                echo ini_get('date.timezone'); ?>
             <?php $data      = date("d/m/Y");  echo "<br>Data atual de hoje <b>".$data."</b>";?><br>
             <?php $data      = date("H:m");    echo "Hora Atual de hoje formato 24h <b>".$data."</b>";?><br>
             <?php $data      = date("h:m A");  echo "Hora Atual de hoje formato 12h <b>".$data."</b>";?>
             <?php $data      = date("P");      echo "<br>Fuso horario : <b>".$data."</b>";?>
             <?php $data      = date("z");      echo "<br><hr>Já se foi <b>".$data."</b> dias do ano";?>
             <br><p>Para as seguintes 1 para sim 0 para nao</p>
             <?php $data      = date("L");      echo "Estamos em um ano bissexto? <b>".$data."</b>";?>
             <?php $data      = date("I");      echo "<br>Estamos em horario de verão ? <b>".$data."</b>";?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Segundo a [documentação da função `date`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php), a letra `m` corresponde ao valor numérico do **mês** (por isso ele está mostrando o valor `04`, pois estamos em abril e quando o segundo parâmetro não é passado, é usada a data atual).

Para os minutos, você deve usar a letra `i`, conforme [indicado na documentação](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php#refsect1-function.date-parameters):

```
 <?php $data      = date("H:i");    echo "Hora Atual de hoje formato 24h <b>".$data."</b>";?><br>
 <?php $data      = date("h:i A");  echo "Hora Atual de hoje formato 12h <b>".$data."</b>";?>
```

---

Sei que parece contra-intuitivo usar `i` para os minutos ("*Por que não é `m`?*"), mas as letras `M` e `m` já são usadas para o mês. Segue um resumo destas letras e seu significado, retirados da [documentação](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php#refsect1-function.date-parameters):

```
+-----------+------------------------------------------------------+---------------+
| Caractere |                     Descrição                        |   Exemplos    |
+-----------+------------------------------------------------------+---------------+
| m         |  Representação numérica do mês, com zeros à esquerda |  De 01 a 12   |
| M         |  Representação textual do mês, com 3 letras          |  De Jan a Dec |
| i         |  Minutos com zeros à esquerda                        |  De 00 a 59   |
+-----------+------------------------------------------------------+---------------+
```

Comment: Valeu mano !!!!